# For loop - First argruement of HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, loops

I have a hashmap that takes two arguments,

```
private HashMap<Integer, car> carList;
```

I have successfully written methods that would allow me to put  new values in the HashMap.
Now I was wondering how I can use a for loop or somethign similar to iterate through the first arguement of my Hashmap. I'm trying to list all the cars that have the same int value (price);

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly that the map key is the price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keySet()` method will allow you to iterate over the map keys...

```
for(Integer price: carList.keySet()) {
    // something
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to refer to the second arguement (the car object), how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
for(Integer price: carList.keySet()) {
    car myCar = carList.get(price);
}
```

Comment: Wow, easier then I thought. I was looking at other SOF answers and they seemed intense. If I wanted to check the second arguement, would I use mapSet instead of keySet?

Comment: No the second argument is not necessarily a set (i.e. no duplicates), because you can have the same value for two different keys. In most cases, I use the code above when iterating through a map. But if you really just want to iterate through the values, use `values()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [KeySet()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#keySet%28%29) method.

From the docs:

> Returns a Set view of the keys contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa. If the map is modified while an iteration over the set is in progress (except through the iterator's own remove operation), the results of the iteration are undefined. The set supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Set.remove, removeAll, retainAll, and clear operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.

.

> I'm trying to list all the cars that have the same int value (price);

Having price as the key is wrong design. you can have a range object as Key. i.e. price range.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve values from a map by key (`Integer` in your case) is as follows:

```
carList.get(<your price>) --> this will get your the value(s) for this price
```

To iterate over all prices, do this:

```
for(Integer price: carList.keySet()) {
   .. your work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, change the variable name to carMap.
Now, you can use one of the following:

```
for(Integer price: carMap.keySet()) {
    // something related to key.
}
```

or:

```
for(Entry<Integer,car> entry: carMap.entrySet()) {
    car c = entry.getValue();
    Integer ket = entry.getKey();
    // something related to key and value.
}
```

But, if the key is price and you hold a **car per price**, you cant have **two cars with same price**.
You might want to use:

```
Map<Integer, List<car>>
```